# set selected tab to down to hide border

Tags: html, css

I am developing a tab strip. I want the selected tab has to overlap 1px on the container div so that it will have look as it is part of the container...
Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTUsh/).
I dont want to make it using script. I would like to prefer CSS style first.If you say that it can't be done using pure CSS, then only can go for script.
It should look as follow:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the [demo](http://jsbin.com/emucof/1)

Add this style to your fiddle

```
.vUiTsContainers {
z-index: 1;
top: -3px;
position: relative;
}

.irmNText {
z-index: 10;
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi now define some css in your css as like this

```
 .vUiTsTabs > ul{
overflow:hidden;  // remove this line
}
```

**or add this css**

```
.vUiTsTabs > ul:after{
content:'';
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
.vUiTsTab.vUiTsTabSel{
position:relative;
}
.vUiTsTab.vUiTsTabSel:after{
content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:-3px;
    height:3px;
    background:#F3F3F3;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/bTUsh/9/)***

Comment: Did you check it in IE too...The tabs are come down if remove overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 1):

I also created a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jampez77/bTUsh/13/) but was beaten to it due to the awfully slow computer I'm using